# Can I still shoot tethered with an EOS 5D mark 1?

Tags: tethering

Just upgraded my mac to 10.11.6 and now I can't seem to find a software to shoot tethered (with clients) for my EOS 5D mark 1. I've done a bit of research and not found anything so far. Lightroom does list it as compatible on the Adobe website, but this isn't actually the case. Does anyone have any suggestions of software I might have missed. Rolling back my operating system is a last resort.

Comment: Meanwhile, you could install Virtual Box and run your old Mac OS to deal with raw files.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is an incompatibility between Canon Cameras and the newest MAC OS. Apple says it's Canon's problem to solve. I doubt Canon will ever update the needed drivers and firmware for a product as old as your EOS 5D classic that was discontinued almost a decade ago. This same issue also makes it impossible to transfer RAW+JPEG images to an OSX 10.10 or higher machine via the camera. The raw files will be corrupted.

For more, please see: [Are Canon 450D RAW files (.cr2) different when shot in RAW+JPEG vs. RAW-only mode (from Lightroom's perspective)?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/90975/15871)